# SDK for Service Management API

Tags: azure, cloud

Just like we have SDK for the Azure Storage [Tables, Blobs, Queues] along with the REST API;

Do we have SDK or library for handling Service Management APIs in c#...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naveen,

Take a look at "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceManagementClient.dll". You can find this along with Azure SDK (C:\Program Files\Windows Azure SDK\v1.4\bin directory). I think this is what you're looking at.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wasn't aware that this existed, mainly because I haven't found it mentioned anywhere else (including in MS documentation).  Is there somewhere I should be looking?

Comment: This library is currently only used by csupload.exe I believe.  If you look at it carefully, it has a lot of spelling errors, etc. in the API, so I don't think you should consider this official in any way (yet).

Comment: Now located here: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\2012-06\bin

Comment: Yeah if you have it installed. -- Where's the NuGet package?

Answer (score 2):

There's not an SDK as such, but there is [this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Azure-CSManage-e3f1882c) from Microsoft which demonstrates how you can work with the REST API in .net.  The other option is you could just use the sample code as it is.

UPDATE:
MS now have a pre-release version of a management library available on [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries).  Brady Gaster has a [blog to get you started](http://www.bradygaster.com/post/getting-started-with-the-windows-azure-management-libraries).

Answer (score -1):

knightpfhor's comment is correct, but since the comment we've released the MAML 1.0 libraries. I think the [Storage Management Client](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Storage/) package might be what you're after.

Comment: `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceManagementClient.dll` is not included in this package.