# Is there a way to know how many instances the webrole contains at current time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database

I am using asp.net 4.0 and c#.net
is there any way to know that by supplying applicationId or webrole name (or both) and know how many instances are present in perticular webrole?

Is there any api available so i can code with c#.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,

```
foreach (var roleDefinition in RoleEnvironment.Roles) 
{ 
   foreach (var roleInstance in roleDefinition.Value.Instances) 
   { 
      Trace.WriteLine("Role instance ID: " + roleInstance.Id, "Information");
   }
}
```

- it's described in more [detail here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.roles.aspx). No need to complicate with the management API really.

Comment: Note: this assumes you are running inside the same "deployment", so on Azure - if you want to check an arbitrary deployment, you need to (1) configure the management certificatae, (2) get the deployment ID, (3) use the Management API posted in Gaurav's Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to make use of Service Management REST API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460806.aspx). Also take a look at the following thread here: [SDK for Service Management API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040119/sdk-for-service-management-api).